# Creating a model to run a complex query

Tags: python, arcmap, arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, sql

I'm just a rookie when it comes to creating models in ArcGIS. I have two shapefiles from which I need to calculate an AVG and a MAX erosion rate for individual properties.

The two shapefiles are:

Coastal_Properties & Coastal_Change

Coastal_Properties has a Property ID (PID), and Coastal_Change has a Rate of erosion in metres per year (RChngMYr).

I'd like to retrieve an **Average and a Max RChngMYr for each individual PID** in the data-set.

I have no problem running this query using SQL select in MapInfo, but am unsure how to go about it in ArcGIS. It will be better in the long run to create a model in Arc as Property boundaries are dynamic, and it would be terrible to have to run the query in MapInfo everyday. I'd like to create a Geoprocess service from this model and use it in a web application where it would return a phrase such as "The Max erosion rate for PID 12345 is 3.1 m/yr".

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: What type of database back-end do you want to run this on? Only Personal Geodatabase (Access) or an ArcSDE RDBMS Geodatabase support Average, Max, Min, Distinct, etc. File geodatabase does not support these functions.

Comment: File geodatabases do support at least the MAX() function via subqueries: "yourField" = (SELECT MAX("yourField") FROM yourFeatureClass).

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the use of File and Personal Geodatabases. I just assumed I could input shapefiles in the model and add the necessary tools to perform the function?

Comment: Have a look at the [Summary Statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001z000000) tool.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help everyone. The Summary Statistics tool is the one I am looking for!

Answer (score 1):

As @blah238 said the best way to do this is by using the **[Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000)** tool.